# I want to use WebSockets to send and receive data in REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, websocket, client

I want to send and receive data using facebook's suggestion 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket 
but when I run the code it fails to import the "WebSocket" and app 
crashes. 
The code in the render method works just fine, but I do not want to 
render a view again and again just to send data. 
I want the code in componentWillMount function to run to send and 
receive data. Please help me. I will be thankful to you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WS from 'react-native-websocket';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default class Example extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {


const ws = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path');

ws.onopen = () => {
  // connection opened

  ws.send('something'); // send a message
};

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  // a message was received
  console.log(e.data);
};

ws.onerror = (e) => {
  // an error occurred
  console.log(e.message);
};

ws.onclose = (e) => {
  // connection closed
  console.log(e.code, e.reason);
};


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WS
          ref={ref => { this.ws = ref }}
          url="http://34.206.187.250:1880/ws/praduman"
          onOpen={() => {
            console.log('Open!')
            this.ws.send('Hello')
          }}
          onMessage={console.log}
          onError={console.log}
          onClose={console.log}
          reconnect 
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native'
import WS from 'react-native-websocket'

export default class Example extends Component {
  _onOpen() {
      console.log('Open!')
      this.ws.send('Hello')    
   }
  _onMessage(event) {
      console.log('Data',event)    
   } 
   _onError(error) {
      console.log('Error',error)   
   }
   _onClose() {
      console.log('Close!')   
   }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <WS
          ref={ref => {this.ws = ref}}
          url="wss://echo.websocket.org/"
          onOpen={() => this._onOpen.bind(this)}
          onMessage={(event) => this._onMessage.bind(this)}
          onError={(error) => this._onError.bind(this)}
          onClose={() => this._onClose.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: just like that..
_opOpen() {